# getting boolean value from text input based on id

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I'm trying get the value from text box using ID but I'm getting boolean value

```html
<input type="text" tabindex="4" class="form-control input-sm" required onkeypress="return onlycode(event,this);" maxlength="40" id="MaterialCode" name="MaterialCode" placeholder="Material Code" autocomplete="off">
```

```js
var matcode = $("#MaterialCode").val();
```

How to get the actual value and what's wrong my html code?

Comment: What do you mean by boolean value from text input? Define your input and output for clarification.

Comment: You can use the `!!` shortcut to convert a value to a boolean: `var matcode = !!$("#MaterialCode").val();`. If that doesn't work for you then please provide more detail in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can get Boolean Value from a variable by Using `!!`

Example :

```
const falsyValue=0
console.log(!!falsyValue) //Log False
const truthyValue=1
console.log(!!truthyValue) //Log True
```

In your case, you need just to use `!!` to convert your value into boolean

```
var marcode = !!$("#MaterialCode").val();
```

Thank you and I hope this answer can help